# MSBuild ReferenceDependencyPaths does not contain nth dependencies

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am attempting to get a list of all my dependencies when I go to build with msbuild. I am trying to use the ReferenceDependencyPaths which I am pretty sure should contain second and nth-order dependencies. When I use this I am getting some of the second order dependencies but not all of them and I am missing all of my 3rd order or higher dependencies. The reason I am attempting to do this is so I can copy my dependencies', dependencies to the bin folder of the project I am building.

I based my solution off of this blog post http://blog.alexyakunin.com/2009/09/making-msbuild-visual-studio-to.html because his solution wasn't working for me out of the box.

This is my solution so far which unfortunately copies some framework dlls but is missing other dlls like ninject.

Does anyone know if their is a different item or property I should be using to get my dependencies', dependencies? Also ninject in this case is coming from nuget, are nuget references resolved some where else and what property or item would they be stored in?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyIndirectDependenciesCondition="'$(CopyIndirectDependencies)'==''">true</CopyIndirectDependencies>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- BuildXxx part -->
<Target Condition="'$(CopyIndirectDependencies)'=='true'"DependsOnTargets="DetectIndirectDependencies" Name="CopyIndirectDependencies">
    <Message Importance="low" Text="Direct dependency: %(ReferencePath.Filename)%(ReferencePath.Extension)" />
    <Message Importance="low" Text="Indirect dependency: %(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Extension) Full Path: @(IndirectDependency)"/>

    <Copy Condition="'%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.RootDir)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Directory)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Extension)'!=''" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" SourceFiles="@(IndirectDependency)">
      <Output ItemName="IndirectDependencyCopied" TaskParameter="CopiedFiles"/>
    </Copy>
</Target>

<Target DependsOnTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences" Name="DetectIndirectDependencies">
<!-- Creating indirect dependency list -->
   <CreateItem Condition="'%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.RootDir)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Directory)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Extension)'!=''" Include="%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.RootDir)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Directory)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceDependencyPaths.Extension)">
     <Output ItemName="IndirectDependency" TaskParameter="Include"/>
   </CreateItem>
</Target>

<!-- Build sequence modification -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <CoreBuildDependsOn>$(CoreBuildDependsOn);CopyIndirectDependencies
  </CoreBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left a comment there,

> It does not work for me when the indirect dependency comes from NuGet
>   packages (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and Newtonsoft.Json). But the
>   tip described in
>   http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2014/05/09/recursively-copying-indirect-project-dependencies-in-msbuild.aspx/
>   solves the issue. I think it uses a more suitable indirect dependency
>   detection approach.

Comment: I looked at that solution and I attempted to use it. I ran into a problem where it is treating nuget packages from our nuget server as part of the solution I am currently building. It then attempts to find it in the folder structures of the solution and fails to since it is in another solution. I have been working with this solution as well but would like to stay away from having that embedded C# in the msbuild file. To fix that solution for my needs I would need some way of using msbuild to get my nuget dependencies and then determine which ones belong to our nuget server.

Comment: @MaxYoung, I could not fully understand what is the problem you met with that solution. You will have to update the question to include necessary info (screen shots and error messages and so on).

Comment: Well turns out the problem was a left over reference to a project that no longer existed in the solution... This solution is working for me now.