# .NET assemblies not being copied to bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I've been wrestling with this problem for a couple weeks now. All my DLLs are referenced properly, are set to Copy Local, and I can build my application fine from my local machine to our build machine. Both my local and the build box have Azure SDK 2.9 installed, but upon running the app in our staging environment, we get

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I enabled the fusion logs on our staging machine, and here is the output:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
```

LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///F:/sitesroot/3/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = F:\sitesroot\3\bin

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: F:\sitesroot\3\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/public_[my DLL]/80b18788/752a457e/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/public_[my DLL]/80b18788/752a457e/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/sitesroot/3/bin/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/sitesroot/3/bin/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/public_[my DLL]/80b18788/752a457e/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/public_[my DLL]/80b18788/752a457e/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/sitesroot/3/bin/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/sitesroot/3/bin/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.EXE.

When I go to D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET, the DLL is not there, so it's obviously looking in the "wrong" place for this DLL.

I'm using VS 2013. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: When I build from my local, I can confirm the bin folder is being cleared before recopying some DLLs back to that folder. The odd thing is that the DLLs that successfully get copied there are no longer referenced anywhere in my code or config files. I also have a post build script but I confirmed that these old DLLs are not referenced there, neither.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I found the Enterprise Library DLL on one of the staging instances, but it's not in the directory the error is referring to. We have a web project that references a second project which is actually an Azure Cloud Service. So it appears the folder for the service is being created under the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, but it's empty.

The DLL is here:

D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\59a01799\5b6b1a2\assembly\dl3\11d624d2\4e820e1f_4413d201

Where I assume "root" is the web application. The error is looking in this folder:

D:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/**[my service class library]**/060e4c2a/e3b3457e/

for the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.DLL. We have a "packages" folder for both the web project and the service class library that's referenced, both containing all the necessary DLLs. So I think there's a setting maybe in the service class library that's still pointing to the root web application project folder to look for the DLLs, I just can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Seems like you're missing the MS Enterprise Library in your staging environment, are you permitted to install it? [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104)

Comment: I get this error for all my references, though, including the newly added Redis SessionStateProvider we're transitioning this application to. And I don't believe the Redis DLLs depend upon the EL DLLs being installed, so I wouldn't think the error I saw with the Redis references would have anything to do with the EL not being in Staging....

Comment: Check if you hit this MSBuild limitation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270073/msbuild-referencedependencypaths-does-not-contain-nth-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that in the pre-build script for the service library that's referenced into the web project, the former developer wrote a file copy program to manually copy certain DLLs to the bin folder. I added these DLLs to that script under the build definition and viola, it worked.

thanks everyone for your responses.